# pyshark packets queue and pickle errors

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyshark

I am trying to use [`pyshark`](https://github.com/KimiNewt/pyshark) to capture packets live.

I get the following error when I try to get the packets from a `multiprocessing.Queue` or to *un-pickle* them:

> python2.7/site-packages/pyshark/packet/layer.py", line 48, in __getattr__
>   val = self.get_field_value(item, raw=self.raw_mode)
>   (... multiple times ...)
>   **RuntimeError**: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`.

I suspect there is a problem when reconstructing the object whether it's retreived from the queue, or unpickled.
Surprisingly though, there are no errors when I am doing this with `Queue.Queue`.

Here is the code used to reproduce this issue :

```
import pyshark
import multiprocessing
import Queue
import cPickle as pickle

# Capture on eth0
interface = pyshark.LiveCapture(interface="eth0")

def queue_test(queue):
    """ Puts captured packets in a queue, then un-queue them and display """
    for packet in interface.sniff_continuously(packet_count=5):
        queue.put(packet)
    while not queue.empty():
        packet = queue.get()
        print "Packet {} {}".format(packet.highest_layer,packet._packet_string)

def pickle_test():
    """ Immediately pickle and unpickle the packet to display it"""
    for packet in interface.sniff_continuously(packet_count=5):
        pickled_packet = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(packet, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL))
        print "Packet #{}, {} {}".format(pickled_packet.highest_layer,pickled_packet._packet_string)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    normal_queue = Queue.Queue()
    process_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()

    # Runs fine
    queue_test(normal_queue)

    # Both crash with a RuntimeError
    queue_test(process_queue)
    pickle_test()
```

Why do I get RuntimeErrors and what can I do about it?
Am I doing something wrong or `pyshark` has a problem doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having not much success here, I posted an issue on [`pyshark`'s Github](https://github.com/KimiNewt/pyshark) and it happens that it was something missing in the library:

> This is caused by the fact that some of the classes packet uses override getattr. Fixed in [541fc52](https://github.com/KimiNewt/pyshark/commit/541fc525a5b600bfd6668765b2fe79ce8149aae0)

Link of this issue : https://github.com/KimiNewt/pyshark/issues/63